# How many symmetric relations have (x,y)

Tags: combinatorics, relations

Set $w = \{x,y,z,w\}$. How many symmetric relations contain $(x,y)$.

I know how to calculate the number of symmetric relations. But how do you calculate how many of those contain $(x,y)$?

Comment: Just write down all the symmetric relations that comes in your mind. ;-)

Comment: I don't want to list anything.

Comment: I would appreciate it if someone could help and be less cryptic than others have been.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Find a bijection between the set of symmetric relations on $\{x,y,z,w\}$ that do contain $\langle x,y\rangle$ and the set of symmetric relations on $\{x,y,z,w\}$ that don’t contain $\langle x,y\rangle$. Then use your knowledge of the total number of symmetric relations on $\{x,y,z,w\}$.

Comment: What? You have to say more. And I would like to add that, if possible, the answer should be easily computable.

Comment: How do you know that there is a bijection?

Comment: @user9915: Assuming that you know how to compute the total number of symmetric relations on a finite set, the answer is very simple. Let $\mathscr{R}$ be the set of all symmetric relations on $\{x,y,z,w\}$. Let $\mathscr{R}_0$ be just those that do not contain $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\mathscr{R}_1$ just those that do contain $\langle x,y\rangle$. Clearly $\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{R}_0\cup\mathscr{R}_1$, and $\mathscr{R}_0\cap\mathscr{R}_1=\varnothing$, so $|\mathscr{R}|=|\mathscr{R}_0|+|\mathscr{R}_1|$. If there’s a bijection between $\mathscr{R}_0$ and $\mathscr{R}_1$, what can you say ...

Comment: ... about $|\mathscr{R}_0|$ and $|\mathscr{R}_1|$? // I know that there’s a bijection because I can see one. It’s not hard to find, and I’m suggesting that it would be worth your while to think about it.

Comment: Why would there be bijection? Is seems like there wouldn't be.I would just divide the total amount by 2 because if there is a bijection then both contribute equally to the size of R.

Comment: Am I understanding you: the size of the set of symmetric relations with (x,y) = the size of symmetric relations without (x,y)? This seems really unintuitive.

Comment: @user9915: That’s exactly what happens. So now all you have to do is find such a bijection. If a symmetric relation $R$ includes $\langle x,y\rangle$, what’s the most obvious way to pair it up with a symmetric relation $R'$ that doesn’t contain $\langle x,y\rangle$?

Comment: Is there a way to solve this without listing things out?

Comment: @user9915: Yes, because the idea works on any finite underlying set, not just on $\{x,y,z,w\}$.

Comment: I have no idea how you come up with the bijection. One set contains all the symmetric relations that contain (x,y). So this set will have (x,y) and (y,x). So only two elements?

Comment: @user9915: No, it will not: it will contain all of the symmetric relations that contain $\langle x,y\rangle$, and of course those will also contain the pair $\langle y,x\rangle$. One of the relations in this set is $\{\langle x,y\rangle,\langle y,x\rangle\}$. At the other extreme, another relation in this set is $\{x,y,z,w\}\times\{x,y,z,w\}$, the total relation on $\{x,y,z,w\}$. Yet another is the relation of equality restricted to $\{x,y,z,w\}$.

Comment: So I see no easy way to form a bijection.

Comment: @user9915: If $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle y,x\rangle\in R$, what is the most obvious way to modify $R$ to get a symmetric relation that does not contain $\langle x,y\rangle$?

Comment: choose two elements that are not $<x,y>$?

Comment: @user9915: Explain: how are you going to use these elements to modify $R$, when what you want to do is get rid of $\langle x,y\rangle$?

Comment: I'm officially have no clue what is going on in terms of setting up a bijection.

Comment: @user9915: I really hate to say anything more: my last comment almost told you in so many words what to do. If $R$ is a symmetric relation that contains $\langle x,y\rangle$, let $R'=R\setminus\{\langle x,y\rangle,\langle y,x\rangle\}$. Show that the map $R\mapsto R'$ is a bijection.

Comment: your last comment makes no sense. I have no idea what you are trying to say.

Comment: @user9915: Then I’m afraid that I’m at a loss as to how to help you, because that last comment tells you exactly what you need to do: it explicitly describes a bijection between $\mathscr{R}_0$ and $\mathscr{R}_1$. All that remains is for you to verify that it actually is a bijection, and since its inverse is obvious, that should be no problem.